# How to configure NVM in AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

I want to configure the **NVM** in way such that, **NVM** will read the data from SW component when the power is ON, and at the time of shutdown SW component will store that value to the memory. 
So right now I'm very much in confusion about the interface. which interface should use and how to map **Pport** and **Rport** with it? 
I have tried with **clientserver** interface but i stuck at port interfaces.? 
Addition to this I want to know that how Sw component and NVM communicate with each other? 
Please help me regarding this query.

Thanks in advance.

Shubham Kulkarni

Answer (score 1):

Use NVM interfaces and NvBlockSwComponentType.Refer the NVM section in  AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE.pdf you will get the idea of how to configure.